# custom attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Student model and a method that does some calculations and returns a value

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  def total_result
     #some calculations
     return result
   end
end
```

Now in my students controller I would like to do the following

```
Student.where("total_result > ?", params[:result])
```

but this brings a PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR. I am using postgres. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Only the attributes of the table can be queried not methods. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to accept user input, do some calculations and return the rows that match.

Comment: When you say return the rows that match, to which attribute you are trying to match the user input?

Comment: To the calculated value. Someone provided what I was looking for. Please check below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
Student.select { |student| student.total_result > params[:result] }
```

*A word of warning:* This will load all students from the database and calculate the value for each of them. This will be slow depending on the number of students in the table.

If you need this more frequently then it would make sense to store/cache the result of the calculation in the database.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Performance is not much of a concern for now. Thanks